# Vba Excel Vlookup Search value is String

Tags: vba, excel

The code below doesn't work

> run time error 1004

`VlookSrc` (Dim As String in VBA) is the value we look for in `Range("KV5:KW105673")`. It's a combination of different cells depending on c and d, and the string `/DIR/` in between.
In the local window it is possible to see that Excel recognizes the correct string.
We use the `IfError` Function because there won't always be value found.
The run error 1004 comes with the worksheetfunction.

```
    If Cells(3, d) = Cells(c, 33) Then
        VlookSrc = Cells(c, 48).Value & "/DIR/" & Cells(4, d).Value
       Cells(c, d) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(VlookSrc, Range(Cells(5, 308), Cells(105673, 309)), 2, False), 0)
    Else
        Cells(c, d) = 0
    End If
```

Comment: Now we found out that the problem was the cell format of the dates.But we still have the problem with the lookup values where no value is found. How is it possible to use iferror worksheetfunction?

Comment: The VLookup function doesn't take a string for its' first argument, that must be a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `IfError()` like that in **VBA**, instead:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim v
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        v = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            Cells(c, d) = .VLookup(VlookSrc, Range(Cells(5, 308), Cells(105673, 309)), 2, False)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `WorksheetFunction` as that always raises run-time errors (plenty about this online) while `Application` allows for an error to be tested.

```
Sub x()

If Cells(3, d) = Cells(c, 33) Then
    VlookSrc = Cells(c, 48).Value & "/DIR/" & Cells(4, d).Value
    Cells(c, d) = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(VlookSrc, Range(Cells(5, 308), Cells(105673, 309)), 2, False), 0)
Else
    Cells(c, d) = 0
End If

End Sub
```